# Most efficient mongo aggregation to unwind and filter: match unwind match vs project and filter

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of documents that each contain arrays. the output i want is the unwinded array elements filtered down by a certain criteria.

i can do this by doing:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
 {
   $unwind: "$myArrayField"
 },
 {
   $match: {
     "myArrayField.myCriteriaField": "myValue"
   }
 }
])
```

but it seems wasteful to unwind everything, so instead i do

```
db.collection.aggregate([
 {
   $match: {
     "myArrayField.myCriteriaField": "myValue"
   }
 },
 {
   $unwind: "$myArrayField"
 },
 {
   $match: {
     "myArrayField.myCriteriaField": "myValue"
   }
 }
])
```

to filter down to viable document candidates, unwind those, and then filter down the unwound elements again since there will be elements that don't match.

alternatively, i can do

```
db.collection.aggregate([
 {
  $project: {
    myArrayField: {
      $filter: {
        input: "$myArrayField",
        as: "element",
        cond: { $eq: ["$$element.myCriteriaField", "myValue"] }
      }
    }
  }
 },
 {
  $unwind: "$myArrayField"
 }
])
```

or even

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
   $match: {
     "myArrayField.myCriteriaField": "myValue"
   }
 },
 {
  $project: {
    myArrayField: {
      $filter: {
        input: "$myArrayField",
        as: "element",
        cond: { $eq: ["$$element.myCriteriaField", "myValue"] }
      }
    }
  }
 },
 {
  $unwind: "$myArrayField"
 }
])
```

which one is the most efficient? i don't understand enough about how the aggregations are run to know what variables it could depend on (collection size, document size, etc).

lastly, the match unwind match seems pretty straightforward but it also just feels wrong to have to do it like that so i'm wondering if i'm missing something.

Comment: 1. Have you checked the [explain](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/)? 2. What are your indexes? 3. Is refactoring array elements into individual documents an option?

Comment: Including a sample document and what you are trying to filter on and the expected end result can help suggest a better solution. Also, lookup this for guidance on aggregation pipeline optimization: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/

Comment: @ray
1. Not yet, thanks!
2. i do have indexes for some of the fields but not all
3. I could put them into individual documents, and maybe I should, but it just felt more like a relational database to have that layout. the collection is for user activity and the way it's organized is by users with an array of activity

Comment: @peter For refactoring into individual documents, you can denormalize the common fields in master document to each sub-documents. You can then build up an index in the new documents(i.e. sub-documents before) to gain performance boost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, You must sure have an index on the field. Using `Explain` to check index hit with `$match` first stage.

Now, we explain your 2 suggestion: `$project` `$filter` `$unwind` vs `$match` `$project` `$filter` `$unwind`:

- `$project` `$filter` `$unwind`: with first stage `$project`, mongodb is doing a collection scan, outputting `ALL documents` in that collection with that field. Now, It's a `full collection scan` and `slow`
- `$match` `$project` `$filter` `$unwind`: with first stage `$match`, mongodb is doing an index scan instead of a collection if It hit an index. After that, stage `$project` will do on a `limit document` that matched. Now, it a `index scan` and `faster` because mongodb only do on some document.

Final, with your 2 option, the second is better

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should have an index on the field.

Then you should limit the result as early as possible meaning the `$match` stage should come first.

The rest is more a matter of taste.